# Visual Studio Smart Indent?

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

Is there a way to auto indent (like ctrl+i in MATLAB) FORTRAN code in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio with the C# keyboard settings, the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

To get the full list of predefined shortcuts, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx (`Edit.FormatDocument`). The list has all keyboard shortcuts from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 3):

Select the code you want to format and press Ctrl+K,F (i.e Ctrl+K then Ctrl+F)

Ctrl+K,D will format the entire document, without changing your cursor position (as Select-All option does).

Comment: I believe you format the entire document by pressing `Ctrl` + `K` `Ctrl` + `D`